# GraphQL passing input arguments to subscriptions

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, subscription, apollo-server

I'm trying to pass an input argument like ID to a GQL subscription.
I'm working with:

```
const { PubSub } =require ('apollo-server');
```

This is the  [apollo subscription reference page](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/)

Basically I'm trying with this easy subscription typedef :

```
 type Subscription{
  subscribe_device(id: String!): device}
```

And this is my subscription resolver :

```
Subscription:{
    subscribe_device:(parent, args, context, info) =>{
        console.log(args)
        subscribe: () => pubsub.asyncIterator('stream')
    }
}
```

Actually without input arguments it works pretty good but in that case it seems to have problems with the asyncIterator

Without input arguments:

```
Subscription:{
    subscribe_device:{
        subscribe: () => pubsub.asyncIterator('stream'),
    }
}
```

Someone know how to manage that issue? How is it possible to input some arguments in subscriptions?
I need it to create dynamically different "stream"

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: read docs: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#subscription-filters

Comment: Yes I've already tried as reported in the documentation using withFilter but the problem is that it just allows to check something.
For example I can check my ID.
My intent is to create separate flows apriori identified by the device ID passed as input argument, not check if i should receive it or not.

Comment: do you know if it is possible?

Answer (score 4):

If you need to describe to channel based on arguments, you just use the `args` to create the channel name based on it. For example:

```
Subscription:{
  subscribeDevice: {
    subscribe: (_parent, args, _context, _info) => { 
      const { someId } = args;
      return pubsub.asyncIterator([`stream_${someId}`])
    }
  }
}
```

This approach is working for me using `apollo-server@2.19.0`.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is additional middleware (which is in the [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#subscriptions-with-additional-middleware)) where you can do stuff between getting something and returning something

In addition, if you want to use the `withFilters` functionality, you can do a general calculation for every possible scenario and filter the desired outcome for a `variables` input and check with the `payload`. For example only those who ask for a specific result will get notified of the changes over socket.